# Programatically insert field value of for a taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called, school and the machine name is field_school_name. The vocabulary has a field called school id (machine name:field_school_id). I am able to add a verb successfully using the following code. How do I add the field value programatically? I want to add '1234' as the school id associated with the verb 'ABCD' I created.

```
$new_term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
    'vid' => 'field_school_name',
    'name' => 'ABCD',
]);

$new_term->enforceIsNew();
$new_term->save();
```

Comment: where are you writing this code? I mean which hook or where this snippet is written

Comment: @ShreyaShetty It is inside a hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should just need to do:

```
$new_term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
 'vid' => 'field_school_name',
 'name' => 'ABCD',
 'field_school_id' => '1234'
]);
```

Comment: That worked! if the field_school_id is a reference entity how do I assign the value?

Comment: You'd need to give it the entity ID  of the entity you want to reference and the entity API should take care of the rest